# SignalR connectionID

Tags: signalr

I'm trying to keep my connection ID even when the page refreshes.
I saved a cookie on the client side, but when trying to retrieve it, the
request.Cookies.Count is 0.

This is the interface implementation:

```
public class ConnectionFactory : IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator
{
    public string GenerateConnectionIdPrefix(IRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Cookies["signalrconnid"] != null)
        {
            return request.Cookies["signalrconnid"].Value;
        }

        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

This is called from the Start() function:

```
 GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator), () => new ConnectionFactory());
```

And this is the client side:

```
function setCookie(cName, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date(2013,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString ());
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + c_value;
}
```

(Don't mind the date)

I saw quite a few posts about it, but I don't get what are the differences.

Comment: I've not used SignalR before so out of interest why would you want to remember the connectionID between requests instead of generating a new guid each time?

Comment: Because I have some logic based on that connectionID. That is, each client is recognized by its ConnectionID, so I can't have a "new" client each time the page refreshes/client goes to dome other page in the site.

Comment: Why not simply create a mapping between connection ID and user and track connections and disconnections to maintain the mapping. That's how our app does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Chris Moutray pointed out, it's probably best not to use the ConnectionId in this way. If I were in your shoes, I would create a SessionId on the client, store it in a cookie or [session storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), pass that sessionId around instead of the connectionId, and then use that as the appropriate mapping between long-term sessions and short-term connections. (The problem with using the UserId as the mapping is that users can be signed on from multiple locations at the same time.)

Comment: I could do that, but than how can I handle the groups? Adding is possible only with the Context.ConnectionID. If it changes every time the client moves from page to page, I'll have to register him all over again.

Comment: That's probably correct, and one of the reasons why I don't use the groups feature within SignalR. So far as I can tell, the logic about who gets what messages is often gonna be more complex than what the SignalR groups feature can handle. So I usually end up keeping a mapping between what I call a "Session" (which can persist across multiple connections) and SignalR connections; and my own "groups" (what I call rooms) are groups of sessions, not connections. So far as I can tell, SignalR Groups are a convenience feature for simple scenarios; and yours isn't.